# How to center my tooltip?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to center my tooltip bubble but no success:( I am guessing that solution is very simple but I just can't make it happen. Can someone help me out? THX!! [Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/Pwcnw/1/)

My code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".menu .a").hover(function() {
var checkWidth = $(this).outerWidth() - $(this).outerWidth()/2;
    $(this).next("em").css({left:checkWidth}).animate({opacity: "show"}, "slow");
    }, function() {
    $(this).next("em").animate({opacity: "hide"}, "fast");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Pwcnw/5/) should work for you. You have to consider the width of the tooltip itself.

```
var checkWidth = $(this).outerWidth() - $(this).outerWidth()/2 - $(this).next("em").outerWidth()/2;
```

Comment: Thank you for helping and I am sorry for being so dumb!!

Comment: Dumb is spending hours trying to solve this when you can be guided to the correct answer. I've been there before - it can be frustrating when you don't see it right away.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
.menu li em {
white-space:nowrap;
background-color:red;
position: absolute;
margin-top:-100px;
margin-left: -50px; /* I added just this line */
text-align: center;
padding: 20px;
font:12px helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
display:none;
}
```